# Lubuntu 18.04 - Custom themes question

Tags: gnome, lubuntu, themes

Today I installed some themes and icons for Lubuntu's desktop, as well as a GNOME theme. However, when I opened the Task Manager, I noticed an increase in the use of RAM, reaching +600 MB without any open program. I wanted to know if this is normal or if there is a way to reduce RAM consumption.

Thank you in advance

Comment: 1: Could you mention the names and source of these themes? 2: Why did you add a GNOME theme to Lubuntu? 3: If you revert to the gtk and icon themes you used before, does the RAM come down to what you experienced before?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `inxi` to show you where your RAM is mostly being used then you can determine if you want to disable items taking up your RAM.

First install `inxi`

```
sudo apt install inxi
```

Then run the following command to give you the first 10 highest memory usage apps:

```
inxi -t m10
```

Here is an example:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ inxi -t m10
Processes: Memory: MB / % used - Used/Total: 1697.9/7976.8MB - top 10 active
           1: mem: 574.19MB (7.1%) command: clamd pid: 1346
           2: mem: 197.59MB (2.4%) command: chrome pid: 31949
           3: mem: 155.93MB (1.9%) command: chrome pid: 31992
           4: mem: 122.07MB (1.5%) command: chrome pid: 32309
           5: mem: 101.23MB (1.2%) command: chrome pid: 32072
           6: mem: 85.83MB (1.0%) command: chrome pid: 730
           7: mem: 85.03MB (1.0%) command: chrome pid: 32115
           8: mem: 79.94MB (1.0%) command: chrome pid: 922
           9: mem: 77.59MB (0.9%) command: chrome pid: 32088
           10: mem: 77.54MB (0.9%) command: chrome pid: 32204
```

I can see that `clamd` which is part of `clamav` is taking over 500MB of RAM, so I could remove the app and that would free up that much more RAM for me.

Here's one without `chrome` running:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ inxi -t m10
Processes: Memory: MB / % used - Used/Total: 1286.6/7976.8MB - top 10 active
           1: mem: 574.19MB (7.1%) command: clamd pid: 1346
           2: mem: 73.07MB (0.9%) command: systemd-journald pid: 379
           3: mem: 64.81MB (0.8%) command: evolution-calendar-factory pid: 8357
           4: mem: 64.07MB (0.8%) command: Xorg pid: 2018
           5: mem: 61.54MB (0.7%) command: xfdesktop pid: 5868
           6: mem: 60.20MB (0.7%) command: evolution-calendar-factory-subprocess pid: 9091
           7: mem: 52.86MB (0.6%) command: redshift-gtk (started by: python3) pid: 5945
           8: mem: 49.09MB (0.6%) command: blueman-applet (started by: python3) pid: 6200
           9: mem: 40.87MB (0.5%) command: xfce4-panel pid: 5860
           10: mem: 36.90MB (0.4%) command: xfce4-terminal pid: 16315
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I prefer `inxi -Fxxxz` when asking people to post info or when posting my own specs. `inxi -r` is also neat for showing software sources including ppas.

Comment: @DKBose I can definitely see why.  =)

Comment: @DKBose Ah, this also works too to get rid of the hostname `inxi -! 31 -Fxxxz`.  I think I found my new favorite command for showing system specs!  =)

Comment: `-!` doesn't seem to work in my version: `Error 22: Unsupported option: -!` I'll poke around for what works in my version.

Comment: But `inxi -Fxxxz --no-host` works in `inxi 3.0.22-00 (2018-08-28)`.

Comment: @DKBose Nice!  Good to know for when I get the newer version.  =)

Comment: All the -! and -@ options were converted to long type options with inxi 2.9 and newer. See -h or man, advanced or debugging options. Or see https://smxi.org/docs/inxi-options.htm or https://smxi.org/docs/inxi-man.htm